# login fails with correct info using PDO

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I converted my login page to use `PDO` but now it's not working. I've run through all kinds of code examples and I can't figure out where I'm going wrong. This looks perfect to me. Also error reporting is fully enabled and yet I don't get any errors. I just get the browser error for the page being "incorrectly configured". FYI, this is a `SQL` db

**//Code**

```
<?php

require ("../Android/connect_db.php");    

$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

try {
    $query_unpw = $db->prepare("
        SELECT member_mast.company_name 
        FROM member_mast 
        WHERE username = ? 
        AND password = ?
    ");

    //$username = $_POST['username'];
    //$password = $_POST['password'];
    $username = 'abc';
    $password = 'abc';
    $name = "name";

    $query_unpw->bindValue(1, $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query_unpw->bindValue(2, $password, PDO::PARAM_STR);   

    $query_unpw->execute();

    $count = $query_unpw->rowCount();

    if ($count > 0) {
        while ($row = $query_unpw->$fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {          
                $name = $row['company_name'];               
        }
        echo $name;     
    } else {
        echo "Username/Password is invalid"; 
    }

} catch(PDOException $e) {
    die($e->getMessage());
}

?>
```

Now the only thing I've been able to figure out after commenting out different pieces of code is that if I comment out the username and password, like this

```
//$username = 'abc';
//$password = 'abc';
```

Then the page loads and just gives me my `else` echo of "Username/Password is invalid". However I don't think I'm using them wrong and I know they are correct. So the obvious question is am I blind, what's wrong here? The bonus question is, since I will be using `_POST` for these variables when this works, am I properly sanitizing the user inputs? Still really new to `PDO` and I want to make sure I'm doing this right. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Maybe you don't have PHP errors enabled at all? If you don't you useually get the 500 Internal Server Error which isn't exactly useful... Try generating a fake PHP error.

Comment: You should avoid storing passwords in your database. Instead you should generate a unique salt for each user and hash their password with it.

Comment: @Paulpro I have 0 control over that unfortunately. I didn't design this database. I'm just using it. That being said, am I correctly sanitizing these inputs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem is here:

```
$query_unpw->$fetch
```

It must be:

```
$query_unpw->fetch()
```

It's a method, so skip that `$` sign.

I suggest you to use ini_set('display_errors', "On") while developing.

Comment: I'm glad there are no kids around because I just used a lot of profanity, very loudly.. lol. Thank you. Sorry for this sillyness.

Comment: on the side note, am I sanitizing these inputs correctly or am I still wide open to injection?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/pdostatement.bindvalue.php : bindValue will escape quotes, so yes, it's enough.

Comment: Ya, this is my first experience with `PHP` and `PDO` so I had heard "escaping" is not "protecting". That being said I added the `PDO::PARAM_STR` so they couldn't just say `1=1`. I was just making sure that was true and I was doing it right.